# How to popup window auomatically?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to automatically popup to another window,for test ,i add a buttom in my GUI,but there is nothing happened.What's more ,i do not want my thread killed,because it has happened before.How can I recorrecct my code?

main.py

from PyQt5 import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    import sys
    import time
    from alert import Ui_Dialog

```
class Ui_Control_system(object):

    def setupUi(self, Control_system):

        Control_system.setObjectName("Control_system")
        Control_system.resize(1004, 722)
        Control_system.setFixedSize(1004, 722)

        Control_system.setWindowIcon(QIcon('images/icon.png'))
        Control_system.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{border-image:url(images/background.jpg)}")

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Control_system)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 170, 752, 245))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(8)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(125)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        Control_system.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0,QTableWidgetItem("机器编号"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,1,QTableWidgetItem("烟雾值"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,2,QTableWidgetItem("火焰值"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,3, QTableWidgetItem("温度值"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,4, QTableWidgetItem("电流值"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,5, QTableWidgetItem("电压值"))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.tableWidget.item(0,0).setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.item(0,1).setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.item(0,2).setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.item(0,3).setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.item(0,4).setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.item(0,5).setFont(font)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 70, 300, 50))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)   
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border-image:url(images/title.png)")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 480, 121, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 480, 121, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 60, 121, 41))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")

        Control_system.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Control_system)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Control_system.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


        self.retranslateUi(Control_system)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Control_system)


    def retranslateUi(self, Control_system):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Control_system.setWindowTitle(_translate("Control_system", "实时监控系统"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Control_system", "开始运行"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Control_system", "停止"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Control_system", "跳转"))

class Control_system(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Control_system):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.jump_to_alert)



    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def jump_to_alert(self):    
        self.popup_window_thread = PopupWindow(self)
        self.popup_window_thread.start()

class Alert(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self):

        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.alert=Ui_Dialog()
        self.alert.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):

        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self,
                                               '警告',
                                               "是否要退出警告？",
                                               QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No,
                                               QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


class PopupWindow(QtCore.QThread): 

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(PopupWindow, self).__init__()
        self.index = 0

    def run(self):
        self.index+=1
        while self.index <= 3:
            alert = Alert()
            alert.show()
            alert.exec()
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):

        self.quit()
        self.wait()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() 

    w = Control_system()

    w.show() 
    app.exec()
```

this is another UI,which will popup to

alert.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
def setupUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
    Dialog.resize(557, 444)
    Dialog.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{border-image:url(images/background.jpg)}")
    Dialog.setWindowIcon(QIcon('images/icon.png'))
    self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
    self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 80, 256, 41))
    self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
    self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
    self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 170, 256, 41))
    self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
    self.textBrowser_3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
    self.textBrowser_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 260, 256, 41))
    self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName("textBrowser_3")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 80, 111, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("微软雅黑")
    font.setPointSize(20)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label.setFont(font)
    self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
    self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 170, 111, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("微软雅黑")
    font.setPointSize(20)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label_2.setFont(font)
    self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
    self.label_2.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.alert = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.alert.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 260, 111, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("微软雅黑")
    font.setPointSize(20)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.alert.setFont(font)
    self.alert.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
    self.alert.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
    self.alert.setObjectName("alert")

    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "警告"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "报警车间"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "报警机器"))
    self.alert.setText(_translate("Dialog", "报警项目"))
```

Comment: your code is too long. Reduce it. Keep only main window, button and pop up window.

Comment: I have reduce my code.it will be clearer

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 

import time 
from alert import Ui_Dialog


class Ui_Control_system(object):

    def setupUi(self, Control_system):

        Control_system.setObjectName("Control_system")
        Control_system.resize(1004, 722)
        Control_system.setFixedSize(1004, 722)

        Control_system.setWindowIcon(QIcon('images/icon.png'))
        Control_system.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{border-image:url(images/background.jpg)}")

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Control_system)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 170, 752, 245))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(8)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(125)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        Control_system.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0,QTableWidgetItem("机器编号"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,1,QTableWidgetItem("烟雾值"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,2,QTableWidgetItem("火焰值"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,3, QTableWidgetItem("温度值"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,4, QTableWidgetItem("电流值"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,5, QTableWidgetItem("电压值"))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.tableWidget.item(0,0).setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.item(0,1).setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.item(0,2).setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.item(0,3).setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.item(0,4).setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.item(0,5).setFont(font)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 70, 300, 50))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)   
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border-image:url(images/title.png)")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 480, 121, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 480, 121, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 60, 121, 41))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")

        Control_system.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Control_system)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Control_system.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


        self.retranslateUi(Control_system)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Control_system)


    def retranslateUi(self, Control_system):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Control_system.setWindowTitle(_translate("Control_system", "实时监控系统"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Control_system", "开始运行"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Control_system", "停止"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Control_system", "跳转"))

class Control_system(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Control_system):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.jump_to_alert)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def jump_to_alert(self):    
        self.popup_window_thread = PopupWindow(self)
        self.popup_window_thread.popup.connect(self.goAlert)            # +++
        self.popup_window_thread.start()

    def goAlert(self):                                                  # +++
        self.alert = Alert()
        self.alert.show()   


class Alert(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self):

        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.alert=Ui_Dialog()
        self.alert.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):

        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self,
                                               '警告',
                                               "是否要退出警告？",
                                               QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No,
                                               QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


class PopupWindow(QtCore.QThread): 
    popup = pyqtSignal()                                             # +++

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(PopupWindow, self).__init__()
        self.index = 0

    def run(self):
#        self.index+=1
        self.popup.emit()                                            # +++

        while self.index <= 3:
#            alert = Alert()
#            alert.show()
#            alert.exec()
            self.index += 1                                          # +++
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.quit()
        self.wait()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() 

    w = Control_system()

    w.show() 
    app.exec()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have try it and make some change in function PopupWindow like                                                                                             class PopupWindow(QThread): 
    
    popup = pyqtSignal()
     
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        
        super(PopupWindow, self).__init__()
        self.index = 0
    
    def run(self):
        
        while self.index <= 3:
            self.index +=1
            self.popup.emit()
            time.sleep(1)
            
    def stop(self):  
        self.quit()
        self.wait()

Comment: @moneyleaf  Sorry, you tried my example and you didn’t succeed?

Comment: What's more.It shows the same windows popup multiply,but I want to popup the same window multiply.How can I change  my code

Comment: it did work after my change.It shows the same windows popup multiply,but I want to popup the same window multiply.How can I change my code